# Fluentvalidation Rules are not reflected in Swagger through MicroElements library

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, swagger, fluentvalidation

I'm using Fluentvalidation on my data transfer objects and would like to show these rules in Swagger through the MicroElements library, but they are not reflected in Swagger UI. I'm using the latest (as of 8 Nov 2021) Swashbuckle, Fluentvalidation and MicroElements libraries.

My MS DI startup registration:

```
public static class SwaggerExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureSwaggerExtensions(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "FooProject", Version = "v1" });
                c.IncludeXmlComments(XmlCommentsFilePath);
            });
        services.AddFluentValidationRulesToSwagger(); <==== MicroElements lib call
    }
    static string XmlCommentsFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            var fileName = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml";
            return Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
        }
    }

}
```

My DTO:

```
public class FooDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

My Validator:

```
public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<FooDTO>
    {
        public FooValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name)
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.Description)
                .NotEmpty()
                .Must(some self-defined rule);
        }
    }
```

Swagger UI output:

```
name    string
nullable: true
description string
nullable: true
```

What steps can I take to further isolate the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you registered the `FooValidator`?

Answer (score 1):

Fix it by changing the version of `MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation` to `6.0.0-beta.3`.

Reference: https://github.com/micro-elements/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation/issues/123